# Use blocks from included files for parent in jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible: I'm trying to get a block in a parent template to be filled out by a file included in a child template of the parent.

The best way to explain this is a test case:

File **t1.djhtml**:

```
<root>
    <block t3_container>
        {% block t3 %}This should be 'CONTENT'{% endblock %}
    </block t3_container>

    <block t2_container>
    {% block t2 %}{% endblock %}
    </block t2_container>
</root>
```

File **t2.djhtml**:

```
{% extends 't1.djhtml' %}

{% block t2 %}
        <block t2>
            {%- include 't3.djhtml' with context %}
        </block t2>
{% endblock %}
```

File **t3.djhtml**:

```
{% block t3 %}
        <block t3>
            CONTENT
        </block t3>
{% endblock %}
```

File **test.py**:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
env  = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(''))
t=env.get_template('t2.djhtml')
print t.render()
```

The output is:

```
<root>
    <block t3_container>
        This should be 'CONTENT'
    </block t3_container>

    <block t2_container>

        <block t2>
        <block t3>
            CONTENT
        </block t3>

        </block t2>

    </block t2_container>
</root>
```

The `t2` block should be empty, and `t3_container` should have block `t3`'s content inside. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use macros in the included file, but instead of including it, you import the macros with context.

---

T1.html

```xml
<root>
  <block t3_container>
    {% block t3 %}{% endblock %}
  </block t3_container>

  <block t2_container>
  {% block t2 %}{% endblock %}
  </block t2_container>
</root>
```

T2.html

```xml
{% extends 'T1.html' %}
{%- from 'T3.html' import inner, inner2 with context %}

{% block t3 %}
    {{ inner2() }}   
{% endblock %}

{% block t2 %}
    <block t2>
        {{ inner() }}
    </block t2>
{% endblock %}
```

T3.html

```xml
{% macro inner2() %}
    <block t3>
        CONTENT '{{ foo+1 }}'
    </block t3>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro inner() %}
  hello
{% endmacro %}
```

test.py

```py
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader("."))
t = env.get_template("T2.html")

print(t.render({"foo": 122}))
```

Comment: Thank you for coming back and adding your solution @Richard! This solution worked great and just saved my night

Comment: t3 must be a macro file, can't be included anymore, that is not the solution, that is workaround