# jinja2: blocks in included files

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use blocks from included files for parent in jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624953/use-blocks-from-included-files-for-parent-in-jinja2)

1. A basic template:

   ```
   {% include "include.html" %}
   ```
2. included file

   ```
   {% block somethingnew %}{% endblock somethingnew %}
   ```
3. a template

   ```
   {% extends "basictemplate.html" %}
   {% block somethingnew %} HEY LOOK AT ME {% endblock somethingnew %}
   ```

3 will not render the block of the included file from the layout. I have a more complex example e.g. I tried to break my main layout into several included files with their own blocks, like a navigation block or a content block, but templates that extend that layout can't put information into blocks in included files. I can sort of see why this might be, but is there anyway around this? My main layout file is getting bulky and I'd like to cut down into more manageable sections, each containing their own blocks. How do I do this, if I can?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624953/use-blocks-from-included-files-for-parent-in-jinja2?rq=1