# Including Blocks from Jinja templates

Tags: python, jinja2

I would like to include blocks from templates instead of macros, as many templates will be including content from many other templates, so `extends` isn't an option.

I've read many answers about this, including [blocks in included files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050009/jinja2-blocks-in-included-files), but the use case always seems to be different. I suspect this cannot be done.

`template1.html`

```
{% block description %}
   <p> Here is a description </p>
{% endblock %}
```

And in `template2.html`

```
{% from 'template1.html' import description %} <- doesnt work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options here.

1. Use a macro, which sounds like something you don't want to do.
2. Use a template_filter.

Assuming you're using Flask, this is as easy as:

```
@app.template_filter('get_block')
def template_filter(block, file):
    html = render_template(file)
    # Then use regex or something to parse
    # or even simple splits (better with named blocks), like...
    content = html.split('{%% block %s %%}'%(block))[-1]
    content = content.split('{%% endblock %%}')[0]
    return content
```

And to use it:

```
{% 'description'|get_block('template1.html') %}
```

Comment: I was hoping I could do this with only Jinja but thanks for the clever suggestion.