# Jinja2 - Override block tag inside include?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Having trouble overriding a block tag inside my include.

I have

base.html

```
<div>
  {% include 'snippet.html' %}
</div>
```

snippet.html

```
<h1>{% block h1 %}{% endblock h1 %}</h1>
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block h1 %}Hello World{% endblock h1 %}
```

I'd expect it to render as:

```
<div>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

But no such luck. Any ideas?

Comment: I wonder if something like [this solution for the opposite problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9674433/3004881) would work for yours, too?

Comment: Yea, macros is another solution. Seemed like a weird way to use them to me though so I just opted with throwing everything in base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up just putting everything in `base.html`